# Nagios 3.5.1 Adding new users to web interface

Tags: .htaccess, nagios

**Scenario:** I have installed Nagios 3.5.1 on CentOS 6.5 setup all the configurations for the server side and hosts (Ubuntu,CentOS & Windows) with success. Everything is looking and running beautifully. Now all the developers and even the CEO and CTO want their own credentials to login into the console.

**Problem:** I've added the users and passwords. And even added them to the cgi.cfg in all areas.
But when I go to test these logins before I send them out, they do not take. Just the login bar refreshes and thats it.

Is this a .htaccess issue ?
Any guidance would be greatly appreaciated
Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you created local users instead of web interface users.

I am not sure about CentOS, I only work with Ubuntu. But I guess it may work almost the same:

- change to Nagios etc folder => `cd /usr/local/nagios/etc`
- add web user (e.g. CEO) => `sudo htpasswd htpasswd.users CEO`
- add a contact in Nagios (e.g. in contacts.cfg)

`define contact{
  contact_name CEO
  use generic-contact 
  alias CEO 
  email ceo@example.com
  can_submit_commands 0
}`

- add a contact group (e.g. in contactgroups.cfg)

`define contactgroup{
  contactgroup_name CEOs
  alias JustWatchDontTouch
  members CEO
}`

- add contact group to host definition

`define host{
  host_name MyServer
  [..]
  contact_groups admins,CEOs
  [..]
}`